# Process frozen when I try to start it hooked to a panel

Tags: c#, windows, process

I need to launch an external .exe application within my windows forms app on a panel.  If I start the process, without placing it on the panel, it's fine but if I place it on the panel the program freezes and does nothing.

I tried to google the problem but I did not find anything,can you help me?.

```csharp
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr Handle, int x, int y, int w, int h, bool repaint);
        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
        private const int GWL_STYLE = (-16);
        public static int WS_BORDER = 0x00800000;
        public static int WS_CAPTION = WS_BORDER;
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
        private const int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;

 string projectDirectory = "C:\\Users\\anten\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\together\\VisualSharp7\\bin\\Debug";
 Visual_Sharp7.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = projectDirectory;
 Visual_Sharp7.StartInfo.FileName = "VisualSharp7.exe";
      if (Visual_Sharp7.Start())
                {

                    IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
                    while ((ptr = Visual_Sharp7.MainWindowHandle) == IntPtr.Zero) ;
                    int WS_VISIBLE = GetWindowLong(Visual_Sharp7.MainWindowHandle, GWL_STYLE);
                    SetWindowLong(Visual_Sharp7.MainWindowHandle, GWL_STYLE, (WS_VISIBLE &  ~WS_CAPTION));
                    SetParent(Visual_Sharp7.MainWindowHandle, panelMain.Handle);
                    ShowWindow(Visual_Sharp7, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
                  }
```

Comment: `while ((ptr = Visual_Sharp7.MainWindowHandle) == IntPtr.Zero) ;` What do you think this does? And what do you think would change that value? Ever?

Comment: Cross-process window hosting requires cooperation between the two processes. You have no such cooperation. Anomalous behavior is not unexpected.